# 415 Unsupported Media Type on POST to .NET Web API

Tags: c#, .net, http, asp.net-web-api2

I have a method which POSTs an Image to a web API. However, I am consistently getting HTTP error 415 Unsupported Media Type.

My host method looks like this:

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("Image/Post")]
public HttpResponseMessage Post(Image image)
{
  // do stuff
  return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Created);
}
```

In my calling method, I have code like this:

```
string url = String.Concat(this.WebApiUrl, "Image/Post");
HttpContent original = new ByteArrayContent(ImageUtility.ImageToByteArray(image));
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
client.BaseAddress = new Uri(url);
HttpResponseMessage response = client.PostAsync(url, original).Result;
response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
```

For reference, the ImageToByteArray() method:

```
public static byte[] ImageToByteArray(Image image)
{
    if (image == null) {throw new ArgumentNullException("image"); }
    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
    {
        image.Save(ms, image.RawFormat);
        return ms.ToArray();
     }
}
```

When I call client.PostAsync().Result, I get the 415. Clearly something is missing here, but I haven't been able to connect the dots. Any ideas?

Comment: So how is the receiving end meant to deserialize the Image? What content-type is the payload?

Comment: It's a JPEG image.

Comment: So set the content-type of the request made by the HttpClient to `image/jpeg`. Now, what do you actually want to do with the image once it's arrived on the server? Do you really want to instantiate an `Image` or just use the bytes from the request stream?

Comment: I tried inserting "original.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("image/jpeg");" but this doesn't help.

Comment: The image will be inserted to a database and the method returns an id.

Comment: So, you don't really need an `Image`. You just want to save the bytes that were sent, yes?

Comment: Yep, I would be perfectly happy to get a byte array.

Comment: I tried changing the method signature to public HttpResponseMessage Post(byte[] image) but I still get the same error.

Comment: Removing the parameter entirely (public HttpResponseMessage Post()) eliminated the problem, and the host correctly executes the method, but how do I get the image from the Request object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WebApi can't bind a stream of image bytes to an `Image` instance. It's better to accept that this is binary data and to act accordingly.

IIRC, you can receive the request body something like this:

```
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Post()
{
    var requestStream = await Request.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();
    var contentType = Request.Content.Headers.ContentType;
    //store content-type and contents of requestStream
    return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Created);
}
```

make sure you set a `content-type` at the sending end.

Comment: Thanks. That seems to be working! I'll do a little more testing.

Comment: This has solved my problem of how to post a binary object to a web API, and receive it in the hosting method. Thanks for your help!